# JSHint not working on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, sublimetext3, jshint

I can't get Sublime to show errors such as missing semicolons using JSHint.

I'm using Sublime Text 3, I used the package controller to install SublimeLinter, then installed SublimeLinter-JSHint. I proceeded to install node.js to Windows via the exe, as well as bash via Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I tried to use `npm install -g jshint` but got an error message I unfortunately did not record. So, I tried to install node.js via bash using:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Which seems to have worked. Now when I use `npm install -g jshint` I get:

```
/usr/bin/jshint -> /usr/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
/usr/lib
└── jshint@2.9.5
```

This makes me think that I've successfully installed JSHint on the Linux side of the bash since it's showing a Linux based path (if that makes sense). I've made sure JSHint is enabled and that it is on the "background" setting.

I'm very new to using terminal commands and installed packages manually, so please take this into account. I've been searching around for an answer for about 2 hours, but I cannot find a similar situation.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `jsHint` is not working in `SublimeText 3`?

Comment: @DavidR That is correct.